# Window function sql

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
UserId   DateOfPurchase   TotalNumberOfPurchase 
10        2020-04-03       2
10        2020-04-03       2
20        2020-04-02       2
20        2020-04-03       2
34        2020-04-01       1
45        2020-04-09       1
67        2020-04-07       1
```

I need to create select * from this table + additional column with values "CustomerRating", first customer with the most TotalNumberOfPurchase.
If two customers have same TotalNumberOfPurchase, top will be with the earliest purchase.
I need to get this:

```
1
1
2
2
3
4
5
```

I know, that I need to use window function line `RANK(), ROW_NUMBER()` but how and which?

Comment: Please post what you have tried with results and also what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `dense_rank()` but you need the minimum purchase date for each user:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by TotalNumberOfPurchase desc, min_DateOfPurchase asc) as ranking
from (select t.*, min(DateOfPurchase) over (partition by userid) as min_DateOfPurchase
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=37685b6988dd5aa0731b59807d7cc032) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution, but still have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 instead of 1,1,2,2,3,4,5

Comment: @Toto6ka . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  This produces exactly the results you specify in the question on the data in the question.  Hence, it answers the question.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, I'm stupid made a mistake when copy it.

Comment: @Toto6ka . . . If this works, you might consider accepting the answer.